# Find FLOATS between FLOATS query with MySQLi PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, floating-point

I'm working with latitude and longitude to get points that are closer to others points. I need to find the latitudes that may exist between 2 numbers in my DataBase, unfortunately I can't find -as an example- 10.0015315 that is between 10.0015316 and 10.0015314. I've used WHERE and BETWEEN that always work with integers but I can't get results using them with these FLOATS. What could be the reason or how can I do this?

```
$latCord = 10.0015315; //I want to find this FLOAT, or a group of FLOATS in a column point_lat BETWEEN 2 numbers.
$radio = 0.0000001; //This changes dynamically
$radioLatUp = $latCord + $radio; // 10.0015316
$radioLatDown = $latCord - $radio; // 10.0015314

//$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pointnet WHERE `point_lat` BETWEEN ? AND ?';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pointnet WHERE `point_lat` >= ? AND `point_lat` <= ?';

$pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
$pre_stmt->bind_param('ss',$radioLatDown,$radioLatUp);
$pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
$result = $pre_stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $point['lat'] = $row['point_lat'];
        $point['long'] = $row['point_long'];
        $point['name'] = $row['point_name'];
        $points[] = $point;
    }

    sendResponse(true,$points);

}else{

    sendResponse(false,'No points close to you');   

}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `d` as your data type in `bind_param` instead of `s`? you might be losing precision because of that... also what is the data type of `point_lat`?

Comment: Oh my...Thanks man, It was a typo there because I'm using doubles and not strings off course. Greetings.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: Totally, that was the problem but I don't know how to accept your comment as the right answer, but this solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably best to just delete the question since the problem is just a typo, the answer is unlikely to help anyone else.